# AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'model' - DeepPavlov

Tags: python, nlp

Всем привет! Пишу бота для ответов на вопросы FAQ, с помощью библиотеки DeepPavlov и потом буду подгружать это в aiogram, чтобы перенести в тг.

```
 # Загрузка модели для генерации ответов
model_config = configs.squad.squad_bert
faq_model_config = model_config.model
faq_model = build_model(faq_model_config, download=True)
```

Выходит ошибка

> faq_model_config = model_config.model
> AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'model'

Что такое, как исправить? Заранее спасибо)